# Sorting array containing dates in String format

Tags: arrays, sorting, date, swift

I have an array like this:

```
["Novembre", "Mars", "Décembre", "Octobre", "Février", "Janvier"]
```

How can i sort it so it becomes :

```
["Décembre", "Novembre", "Octobre", "Mars", "Février", "Janvier"]
```

Comment: Is this array always going to contain months of the year?

Comment: Yes it will always be months

Comment: Are those array items strings "Novembre"?

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to put the ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calendar month names are not alphabetized so you need to provide the custom sort order value for each month.

```
var array = ["Novembre", "Mars", "Décembre", "Octobre", "Février", "Janvier"]
var sortedArray = array.sorted({
    let dict = ["Janvier":1,"Février":2,"Mars":3,"Décembre":12,"Novembre":11,"Octobre":10]
    return dict[$0] > dict[$1]
})

println("sorted \(sortedArray)")
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same, but surely it is better to generate the dictionary by rule than to have to type the month names and numbers yourself:

```
var names:[String] = []
if let cal = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian) {
    cal.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr")
    names = cal.monthSymbols as [String]
}
var months : [String:Int] = [:]
for (ix,name) in enumerate(names) {
    months[name] = ix
}
// now we are ready
let data = ["Novembre", "Mars", "Décembre", "Octobre", "Février", "Janvier"]
let result = data.sorted {months[$0.lowercaseString] > months[$1.lowercaseString]}
```

Comment: And nicely addresses the sorting, too.